# ActiveRecord `.references` joining more tables than necessary? (and causing an error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

#### Model Layout

```
Article (has_many :attachments, :comments, :tags)
  - id: string

Comment (has_many :attachments)
  - id: integer
  - article_id: string

Attachment
  - id: integer
  - reference_type: string
  - reference_id: string

Tag
  - id: integer
  - article_id: string
```

#### Erroneous Query

In the `rails console` I run:

```
Article.includes(:tags, :comments => :attachments).references(:tags)
```

And the resulting error is:

```
Article.includes(:tags, :comments => :attachments).references(:tags)
  SQL (0.7ms)  SELECT "articles"."id" AS t0_r0, "articles"."created_at" AS t0_r1, "articles"."updated_at" AS t0_r2, "tags"."id" AS t1_r0, "tags"."article_id" AS t1_r1, "tags"."created_at" AS t1_r2, "tags"."updated_at" AS t1_r3, "comments"."id" AS t2_r0, "comments"."article_id" AS t2_r1, "comments"."created_at" AS t2_r2, "comments"."updated_at" AS t2_r3, "attachments"."id" AS t3_r0, "attachments"."reference_type" AS t3_r1, "attachments"."reference_id" AS t3_r2, "attachments"."created_at" AS t3_r3, "attachments"."updated_at" AS t3_r4 FROM "articles" LEFT OUTER JOIN "tags" ON "tags"."article_id" = "articles"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "comments" ON "comments"."article_id" = "articles"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "attachments" ON "attachments"."reference_id" = "comments"."id" AND "attachments"."reference_type" = $1  [["reference_type", "Comment"]]
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying = integer
LINE 1: ...OIN "attachments" ON "attachments"."reference_id" = "comment_...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
: SELECT "articles"."id" AS t0_r0, "articles"."created_at" AS t0_r1, "articles"."updated_at" AS t0_r2, "tags"."id" AS t1_r0, "tags"."article_id" AS t1_r1, "tags"."created_at" AS t1_r2, "tags"."updated_at" AS t1_r3, "comments"."id" AS t2_r0, "comments"."article_id" AS t2_r1, "comments"."created_at" AS t2_r2, "comments"."updated_at" AS t2_r3, "attachments"."id" AS t3_r0, "attachments"."reference_type" AS t3_r1, "attachments"."reference_id" AS t3_r2, "attachments"."created_at" AS t3_r3, "attachments"."updated_at" AS t3_r4 FROM "articles" LEFT OUTER JOIN "tags" ON "tags"."article_id" = "articles"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "comments" ON "comments"."article_id" = "articles"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "attachments" ON "attachments"."reference_id" = "comments"."id" AND "attachments"."reference_type" = $1
    from /Users/jeremy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@rails5/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:598:in `async_exec'
    from /Users/jeremy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@rails5/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:598:in `block in exec_no_cache'
    from /Users/jeremy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@rails5/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:566:in `block in log'
    from /Users/jeremy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@rails5/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
    from /Users/jeremy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@rails5/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:560:in `log'
    from /Users/jeremy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@rails5/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:598:in `exec_no_cache'
    from /Users/jeremy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@rails5/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:587:in `execute_and_clear'
    from /Users/jeremy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@rails5/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:103:in `exec_query'
    from /Users/jeremy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@rails5/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:373:in `select'
    from /Users/jeremy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@rails5/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:41:in `select_all'
    from /Users/jeremy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@rails5/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:70:in `select_all'
    from /Users/jeremy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@rails5/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:389:in `find_with_associations'
    from /Users/jeremy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@rails5/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/relation.rb:699:in `exec_queries'
    from /Users/jeremy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@rails5/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/relation.rb:580:in `load'
    from /Users/jeremy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@rails5/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/relation.rb:260:in `records'
    from /Users/jeremy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@rails5/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/relation.rb:683:in `inspect'
... 1 levels...
    from /Users/jeremy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@rails5/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/jeremy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@rails5/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `console'
    from /Users/jeremy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@rails5/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/jeremy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@rails5/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jeremy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@rails5/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/jeremy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@rails5/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
    from /Users/jeremy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@rails5/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/jeremy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@rails5/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/jeremy/Documents/Synack/Code/experiments/joins-test/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jeremy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@rails5/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
    from /Users/jeremy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@rails5/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in load'
    from /Users/jeremy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@rails5/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/jeremy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@rails5/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
    from /Users/jeremy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/jeremy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
```

#### Successful Query

Without a `.references()` clause, the query works properly, and fetches all models separately, creating four separate requests.

In the `rails console` I run:

```
Article.includes(:tags, :comments => :attachments)
```

And I see:

```
Article.includes(:tags, :comments => :attachments)
  Article Load (5.1ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles"
  Tag Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" WHERE "tags"."article_id" = 'seedacorn-123'
  Comment Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."article_id" = 'seedacorn-123'
  Attachment Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "attachments".* FROM "attachments" WHERE "attachments"."reference_type" = $1 AND "attachments"."reference_id" IN ('1', '2')  [["reference_type", "Comment"]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<article id: "seedacorn-123", created_at: "2016-07-15 22:41:27", updated_at: "2016-07-15 22:41:27">]>
```

### The Question

So I guess, what I'm really wondering, is why ActiveRecord adding *all* of the included models to the `JOIN` rather than just those that I added to the `.references()`? Is this intended as a performance benefit? Or is this needed for some other reason?

I did not add `:comments` or `:comments => :attachments` to the `.references()`, but they were still added to the `JOIN`. This is causing a typecasting error, but I'm wondering why this is even happening in the first place?

### Ask

If you know how to resolve this with some kind of creative solution, I'm trying desperately to figure it out. The core problems is that my polymorphic `Attachment` model can reference other models with either String or Integer primary keys, and so its `reference_type` is a string. Then this is not getting properly typecast when querying other models, in the case where `JOIN`'s are introduced.

Comment: What's `Vulnerability`?

Comment: Updated...meant to replace with `Article`. sorry about that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer to this question after posting an issue on [github.com/rail/rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25893).

As it turns out, this is known (and unfortunately expected) behavior in Rails. If you require that an association be loaded with a separate query and **not** as part of a `JOIN`, you can use `preload` instead of `includes`, which will always load the association as in a separate query.

Likewise, if you want to force an association to load as part of a `JOIN`, and you're not using `includes`, you can replace `references` with `eager_load`.

So

```
Article.includes(:tags, :comments => :attachments).references(:tags)
```

Would become

```
Article.preload(:tags, :comments => :attachments).eager_load(:tags)
```